# How to split correctly my index.js into server.js and app.js?

Tags: node.js, express, es6-modules

I have the current index.js file which is running fine... but for use in my testing strategy, I want to split it into 2 files:  `server.js` and `app.js`

I am getting an error stating that my `app.js` is not a function.. what's wrong with my coding ?

**index.js**

```
import express from 'express';
import express_graphql from 'express-graphql';
import { buildSchema } from 'graphql';

// Construct a schema, using GraphQL schema language
const schema = buildSchema(`
  type Query {
    message: String
  }
`);

// Root resolver
const root = {
  message: () => 'Hello World!'
};

// Create an express server and a GraphQL endpoint
const app = express();
app.use('/graphql', express_graphql({
  schema: schema,
  rootValue: root,
  graphiql: true
}));

/* eslint-disable no-console */
app.listen(4000, () => console.log('Express GraphQL Server Now running On localhost:4000/graphql'));
```

SPLITTED INTO :

**server.js**

```
import app from './app';

/* eslint-disable no-console */
app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log('Express GraphQL Server Now running On localhost:4000/graphql');
});
```

**app.js**

```
import express_graphql from 'express-graphql';
import { buildSchema } from 'graphql';
import express from 'express';

 export default function () {

  // Construct a schema, using GraphQL schema language
  const schema = buildSchema(`
    type Query {
      message: String
    }
  `);

  // Root resolver
  const root = {
    message: () => 'Hello World!'
  };

  // Create an express server and a GraphQL endpoint
  const app = express();
  app.use('/graphql', express_graphql({
    schema: schema,
    rootValue: root,
    graphiql: true
  }));

}
```

**console.log**

```
yarn start
yarn run v1.9.4
$ babel-node src/server.js
/Users/yves/Developments/WIP/NODE/nodeGraphQL/src/server.js:10
_app2.default.listen(4000, () => {
              ^

TypeError: _app2.default.listen is not a function
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yves/Developments/WIP/NODE/nodeGraphQL/src/server.js:4:5)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
    at loader (/Users/yves/Developments/WIP/NODE/nodeGraphQL/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:144:5)
    at Object.require.extensions.(anonymous function) [as .js] (/Users/yves/Developments/WIP/NODE/nodeGraphQL/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:154:7)
    at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:694:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yves/Developments/WIP/NODE/nodeGraphQL/node_modules/babel-cli/lib/_babel-node.js:154:22)
    at Module._compile (module.js:653:30)
error Command failed with exit code 1.
```

thanks for feedback

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `app.js` is exporting a *function*, which `server.js` imports. But, you don't actually call the function. Given this structure, your `server.js` would need to look more like:

```
import app from './app';

app().listen(4000, () => {
    // ....
});
```

That said, you also have a problem in that the function `app.js` is exporting doesn't actually return a value, it creates the express server but doesn't return it. So you'd also need to tweak `app.js`, by adding a return to the end of the method body:

```
  const app = express();
  // ....

  return app;
}
```

Give that a shot!

Comment: Thanks a lot... it's running as well as my original index.js file !

Answer (score 1):

You should `return app` in the function that you export from your app.js file, import it in your server.js file then call the function this way `app().listen`. The app you are returning is the initialized `const app = express()` function which contains the `listen()` property your server depends on to run.

Answer (score 0):

valid code as per @Elliot and @Ekpin answers... ( @Elliot was first on the line )

**app.js**

```
import express_graphql from 'express-graphql';
import { buildSchema } from 'graphql';
import express from 'express';

 export default function () {

  // Construct a schema, using GraphQL schema language
  const schema = buildSchema(`
    type Query {
      message: String
    }
  `);

  // Root resolver
  const root = {
    message: () => 'Hello World!'
  };

  // Create an express server and a GraphQL endpoint
  const app = express();
  app.use('/graphql', express_graphql({
    schema: schema,
    rootValue: root,
    graphiql: true
  }));

  return app;

}
```

**server.js**

```
    import app from './app';

    /* eslint-disable no-console */
    app().listen(4000, () => {
      console.log('Express GraphQL Server Now running On localhost:4000/graphql');
    });
)
```